# Why Iterating through the enum return duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, enums, registry

I am working now on some stuff regarding registry.

I checked the enum `RegistryRights` in `System.Security.AccessControl`.

```
public enum RegistryRights
{
    QueryValues = 1,
    SetValue = 2,
    CreateSubKey = 4,
    EnumerateSubKeys = 8,
    Notify = 16,
    CreateLink = 32,
    Delete = 65536,
    ReadPermissions = 131072,
    WriteKey = 131078,
    ExecuteKey = 131097,
    ReadKey = 131097,
    ChangePermissions = 262144,
    TakeOwnership = 524288,
    FullControl = 983103,
}
```

This enum is a bitwise,And I know that enums can contains duplicate values.
I was trying to iterate through the enum by this code:

```
 foreach (System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights regItem in Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights)))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(regItem.ToString() + "  " + ((int)regItem).ToString());
        }
```

also Enum.GetName(typeof(RegistryRights),regItem) return the same key name.

and the output I got is:

```
QueryValues  1
SetValue  2
CreateSubKey  4
EnumerateSubKeys  8
Notify  16
CreateLink  32
Delete  65536
ReadPermissions  131072
WriteKey  131078
ReadKey  131097
ReadKey  131097
ChangePermissions  262144
TakeOwnership  524288
FullControl  983103
```

Can someone please tell me **why** do I get duplicate keys?("ReadKey" instead of "ExecuteKey")
**How** can I force it to cast the int to the second key of the value ?
and why ToString does not return the real key value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would have to iterate over the enum Names rather than values. Something like:

```
foreach (string regItem in Enum.GetNames(typeof(RegistryRights)))
{
    var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(RegistryRights), regItem);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(regItem + "  " + ((int)value).ToString());
}
```

As to why this happens, there's no way for the runtime to know which name to return if the values are duplicate. This is why iterating through the names (which are guaranteed to be unique) produces the results you're looking for.

Comment: This answers to `How`, but not answer to `Why`?

Answer (score 3):

Note that both `ReadKey` and `ExecuteKey` have same values defined which equals `131097`.

```
ExecuteKey = 131097,
ReadKey = 131097,
```

So technically both are equal.

Comment: This looks like intending to answer to `Why` (although not really clear) but not answer to `How`?

Comment: I know they have the same value, but I was "expecting"(shame on me) that when I iterate through the enum it will know which key it iterating on otherwise to show only one value of each kind.