# String.Format return different enum values for same code. If I add more than 45 fields in enum

Tags: c#, string, enums

This is a very weird behavior. Below is the code. If i add one more enumeration to the testEnum [i.e more than 45] then the string.Format returns "NoUnit". If enumerations is less than 45, same code returns "Dimensionless". What am i missing?

```
public enum testEnum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ""
    /// </summary>
    NoUnit = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// ""
    /// </summary>
    Dimensionless = NoUnit,

    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,k,i,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,a1,b2,c3,d4,e5,v5,b4,b5,h6,j6,j7,f4,f5,k8,k9,p9,p8,k7,l8,
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    testEnum yUnit = testEnum.NoUnit;
    string headerTitle = string.Empty;
    headerTitle = string.Format("Test Diagram [{0}]", yUnit);
    Console.WriteLine(headerTitle);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You're not missing anything, if you have 2 names in the enum use the same value, you're not guaranteed to get a specific one back if you ask for the string name of the value. This is done using reflection and reflection does not guarantee member order as such. Basically, you can't rely on either one being returned.

Comment: Why it happens once you add more than 45 elements, that might just be some internal data structure that has to resize a dictionary or whatnot, but since you're not guaranteed to get "the right name" anyway, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question so I'll refrain from posting an answer, but this is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_ToString_System_String_): **Notes to Callers
If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.**

Comment: Thanks much for the comments and the link to the document Lasse.  I wont spend any more time wondering  :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Iterating through the enum return duplicate keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558574/why-iterating-through-the-enum-return-duplicate-keys)